# PDO stops working after PHP version is upgraded to PHP 5.5

Tags: php, pdo

My application works fine, but now when I updated PHP version all on a sudden, PDO module is stopped working.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=VL", $username, $password);
    echo "123";var_dump($conn);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

But it is not giving any exception , nothing is getting print in var_dump(). Please help in understanding what may be the issue.

Comment: Do you have error/notice reporting turned on ?

Comment: Did you reload the PDO module after you upgraded PHP. Check the php.ini file.

Comment: Is the pdo_mysql module installed/enabled?

Comment: Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
while restarting apache

Comment: @Ryan Vincent i have done phpInfo(); Also: var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__); but long information is getting printed. not able to understand which part should i look for

Comment: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' in /home/dpk/ttt.php on line 8
string(5) "FILE8"... can you please help me in error while restarting apache. which i had mentioned in above comment

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  how to reload PDO module... i have tried to restart apache but got above error

Comment: Hi Ryan Vincent any track what can be the issue

Comment: $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=VL", $username, $password); var_dump($conn); printing nothing

Comment: please help to find the clue about the issue